# button does not show the full text in iPhone SE

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, autolayout

I have 3 `buttons` in a `view`. all the buttons show the `button title` with the  same `number of lines`. i.e. if **1 button** is showing text in 2 lines the other two will show the same. This issue is affecting me mainly when working with `iPhone SE's`. it showing like below,

[image: Button design]

**This is how Attribute Inspector looks**

[image]

font size is -

[image]

Comment: you can do it by calculating the `parentView.frame.size .width` and then adding width for the three button `parentView.frame.size .width/3`

Comment: I am asking about text line not for button size

Comment: `btn.titleLabel.numberOfLines` can be used but for it your button width should be same for better UI

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this,

1. create an `IBOutlet` connection from your `button` to `controller`.
2. `Ex : think your button outlet name is` -> **testButton**
3. then in viewdidload:

   ```
          testButton.setTitle("Delete\n Tender", for: .normal)
          testButton.titleLabel?.numberOfLines = 2
   ```

Hope this will help to you.